# currying with python and lambda functiom

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

Let's say I have an procedural code in python like this,

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 9, (4,4))
```

```
def foo(x):
  y = np.rot90(x)
  y = np.rot90(y)
  return y

# This can be written as 

y = rot90(rot90(x))
```

The above foo function can be written as a composition of functions as all the functions take single argument and returns the single argument.

Consider the another `foo` function as below which is bit complicated than the previous where all the arity of the functions are not same upon applying the functions

```
def swap_a_with_b(x, a, b):
  x[x==b] = 100
  x[x==a] = b
  x[x==100] = a
  return x

def foo(x):
  a, b = np.argsort(np.bincount(x.flatten()))[-2:]
  return swap_a_with_b(x, a, b)
```

how can I write the function `foo` in the form of composition of functions, where primitive function can be any numpy functions and `swap_a_with_b`, I can use all the primitive functions, extra helper function `swap_a_with_b` and any anonymous `lambda` function.

I know it can be done if we use `functools.partial` to define a specific function for the specific values of `a` and `b` for the higher order function `swap_a_with_b`, but can we do this as just a function composition with `lambda` ?

Comment: This is not currying.

Comment: Anyway, are you asing for `y = swap_a_with_b(x, *np.argsort(np.bincount(x.flatten()))[-2:])`?